# python - robot framework autoitlibrary - Class not registered

Tags: python, robotframework

Trying basic tutorial using the AutoItLibrary, I get this error:

```
Error in file '*:\*********\ui_robot_testing\test.robot' on line 2: Initializing library 'AutoItLibrary' with no arguments failed: com_error: (-2147221164, 'Class not registered', None, None)
```

Here is my setup:

```
robot --version 
Robot Framework 6.1.1 (Python 3.9.2 on win32)
```

How to reproduce

```
py -m pip install robotframework
py -m pip install robotframework-autoitlibrary
regsvr32.exe *:\UserData\*******\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\RobotFramework\Extensions\AutoItLibrary\AutoItX3.dll
```

robot file:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    AutoItLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Open Notepad And Write Text
    Run    some/executable/path.exe
    Win Wait Active    Untitled - VisualStudio2019
    Send    Hello, Robot Framework!
```

thanks for your time trying to help me